# Critical values for Lomax distribution in Anderson-Darling Test

Tags: goodness-of-fit

Is there any way to find the critical values for Anderson-Darling test on Lomax distribution?
I have searched the literature but have not found any tabulated values. I specifically need to find the correspondence between p-values and critical values.